# How do I force Firefox to remember a password?

Tags: firefox, passwords

There are a couple of sites that I use (off the top of my head, the [Xbox Live portal](http://live.xbox.com) and [del.icio.us](http://del.icio.us)) for which Firefox will not offer to remember my password. Any ideas on how to force Firefox to recognize the username/password fields for these pages?

**EDIT:** My primary laptop is Windows, but I believe I've seen the same behavior for these sites on my MacBook as well. Also, these sites are not in my *Exceptions* list.

Comment: Windows...os x...linux?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a bookmark with the following code. You click on the bookmark before you login to a site. Firefox will now allow you to save the password. Any Microsoft property won't allow you to save the password.

```
javascript:(function(){var%20ca,cea,cs,df,dfe,i,j,x,y;function%20n(i,what){return%20i+"%20"+what+((i==1)?"":"s")}ca=cea=cs=0;df=document.forms;for(i=0;i<df.length;++i){x=df[i];dfe=x.elements;if(x.onsubmit){x.onsubmit="";++cs;}if(x.attributes["autocomplete"]){x.attributes["autocomplete"].value="on";++ca;}for(j=0;j<dfe.length;++j){y=dfe[j];if(y.attributes["autocomplete"]){y.attributes["autocomplete"].value="on";++cea;}}}alert("Removed%20autocomplete=off%20from%20"+n(ca,"form")+"%20and%20from%20"+n(cea,"form%20element")+",%20and%20removed%20onsubmit%20from%20"+n(cs,"form")+".%20After%20you%20type%20your%20password%20and%20submit%20the%20form,%20the%20browser%20will%20offer%20to%20remember%20your%20password.")})();
```

Comment: why should I trust a cryptic javascript code from someone I don't know??? Specially when he tells me to add it as a bookmarklet!??

Comment: This does the trick. Thanks, my password for delicious was pretty damn long.

Comment: @hasen j: that's why i give credits where due :) https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/forms.html#remember_password

Comment: Why should I trust an extension that's being offered as a binary file and I don't know the developer? Why there isn't an extension that points to https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/? Any solution to this question can be considered unsafe.

Comment: People who adopt a fundamental attitude like "why should I trust that?" are in their right to do so, but ultimately, should consider this classic paper on the issue of trust in the computer software world http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/ken/trust.html

Comment: @hasen j, why trust anything from anyone! That being said, I cannot quickly see much encoding / reference to third party sites.

Comment: @Molly That's from where I got it. Does anyone check for these links?

Answer (score 2):

There is a firefox extension [save-my-password](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-my-password/) which enables to manually insert the password into the password manager for the current site. Then firefox will be prompting the password for this site

Answer (score 1):

setatakahashi's solution works perfectly.

What you could also do is install this addon: http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/

It will add a toolbar which allows you many things. The "Forms" tab has an option called "Enable Auto Completetion".
Click that, and login. Firefox will offer to remember your password.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Lastpass for your passwords which don't get stored in Firefox at all, but are encrypted using the browser just like the passwords that are stored within FF. They have a bokmarklet available as well as extensions for Firefox and an Add-On for IE.

You can find them at either http://www.lastpass.com or through the Mozilla add-ons directory.